# Pointer of struct as return value for c++ dll function

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct, pinvoke

I've been several days into this, and I've read a lot of questions that helped me to arrive to where I am right now.  But I still  need some help.

I will explain.  I have a C++ DLL that I want to wrap for use it in c#.  I have the documentation of the DLL, but I can't change anything of it.  A lot of functions work with basic dllimport setup, but I have some functions that doesn't work properly, this is one of them:

```
DLL documentation
struct stChannel LookForAvailableChannels (const char *dataBaseFolder, int serialNumber, double firstLogTime, double lastLogTime)
```

I also have these structs:

```
struct stChannelInfo
{
 char ChannelTag[17];
 char ChannelEnabled;
}

struct stChannel
{
 int ChannelNumber;
 struct stChannelInfo *ChannelInfo;
}
```

So trying different things, and after reading a lot, I've come to a solution that "partialy" works:

```
C# Code
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct stChannelInfo
    {
        public IntPtr ChannelTag;
        public byte ChannelEnabled;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct stChannel {
        public int ChannelNumber;      
        public stChannelInfo ChannelInfo;
    };

[DllImport("NG.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern stChannel LookForAvailableChannels(string dataBaseFolder, int serialNumber, double firstLogTime, double lastLogTime);

stChannel Estructura = new stChannel();
```

I have a button that calls fires up this code:

```
Estructura = LookForAvailableChannels("C:\\Folder", 12345678, FechaInicio, FechaFinal);
```

Then I marshal Estructura.ChannelInfo.ChannelTag:

```
string btListFile = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Estructura.ChannelInfo.ChannelTag);
```

This actually works, it returns data I know it's correct.  But I'm only receiving the first element of an array, because stChannelInfo struct inside stChannel is a pointer, and I don't know how to handle this in c#.

It should be done in a way that this code I use right now:

```
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Estructura.ChannelInfo.ChannelTag);
```

Should be

```
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Estructura.ChannelInfo[i].ChannelTag);
```

But everything i've used right now just doesn't work.  I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Thanks to user Adriano Repetti now I have this:

C# Code
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct stChannelInfo
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 17)]
            public string ChannelTag;
            public byte ChannelEnabled;
        };

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct stChannel {
        public int ChannelNumber;
        public IntPtr ChannelInfo;
    };

[DllImport("NG.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern stChannel LookForAvailableChannels(string dataBaseFolder, int serialNumber, double firstLogTime, double lastLogTime);

stChannel Estructura = new stChannel();
```

I have a button that calls fires up this code:

```
Estructura = LookForAvailableChannels("C:\\Folder", 12345678, FechaInicio, FechaFinal);

var channelinf = (stChannelInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Estructura.ChannelInfo, typeof(stChannelInfo));


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var ptr = IntPtr.Add(Estructura.ChannelInfo, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(stChannelInfo)) * i);
            var channelll =  (stChannelInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(stChannelInfo));
        }
```

The problem now it's that I get an AccessViolationException here:

```
Estructura = LookForAvailableChannels("C:\\Folder", 12345678, FechaInicio, FechaFinal);
```

But I don't really know why, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your array `ChannelInfo` has not fixed size then *automatic* marshaling with `[MarshalAs(UnamangedType.LPArray)]` doesn't work. Doing marshaling manually means that `ChannelInfo` must be declared as `IntPtr`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct stChannel {
    public int ChannelNumber;      
    public IntPtr ChannelInfo;
};
```

When you need it you need to *convert* it to a struct:

```
var channelInfo = (stChannelInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
    Estructura.ChannelInfo,
    typeof(stChannelInfo));
```

Now you're accessing to first element, to access array items you need an offset:

```
var ptr = IntPtr.Add(Estructura.ChannelInfo,
    Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(stChannelInfo)) * itemIndex);
```

And then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` over it. You may want to write an helper method:

```
static GetUnmanagedArrayItem<T>(IntPtr baseAddress, int index) {
    var ptr = IntPtr.Add(baseAddress, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * index);
    return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
}
```

Used like this:

```
var channelInfo = GetUnamangedArrayItem<stChannelInfo>(Estructura.ChannelInfo, 1);
```

---

You didn't explicitly ask but note that you can't *manually* marshal *unamanged* `char*` string with `IntPtr` for a fixed length char array

<del>You may declare it as string decorating that field with `UnmanagedType.LPStr`:

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst=17)]
    public string ChannelTag;</del>

**EDIT**: I was wrong about this, `String` can't be used in return values because it's not [blittable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), of course `IntPtr` is wrong because you have a fixed length array, I'd suggest to use:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 17)]
public byte[] ChannelTag;
```

You can get original string simply decoding this array with `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(yourStruct.ChannelTag);`. As alternative you may follow what suggested by JaredPar in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10320690/1207195).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, it really helps me to understand what is going on.  Everything is ok, but this part 'Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T) * index))' is not compiling.  This operator can't be applied to these two types, I don't know to solve it.

Comment: If you do _manual_ marshaling then it should also work. Little bit _annoying_ but with some helper functions it may be reasonable. What I'd suggest is to write a complete managed wrapper around them.

Comment: Edited my previous comment :D

Comment: Missing parenthesis, fixed.

Comment: Ok!  Now when I call the function I get an AccessViolationException.  I call the function like this. stChannel Estructura = LookForAvailableChannels("C:\\ProteinasLogger", 14184111, FechaInicio, FechaFinal).  If I change Estructura from stChannel to var it works but the results are not what I expected.

Comment: Also change ChannelTag to string (see second part). Fixed length char array is not marshaled correctly to IntPtr

Comment: Yes, this part is also modified.  I've made all the changes you pointed out in your answer, but I get that AccessViolationException.

Comment: Rather than posting new code, it would be better for the new question to be just that – a new question. It's not realistic to expect somebody to debug all your consequential bugs too.

Comment: Yes, I will post all the changes.  Yeah, I'm not expecting a debug, I'm just pointing out that the code almost works :)

Comment: I've created a new question, as suggested :).   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424129/accessviolationexception-with-c-dll