# Use UTD from header in C#

Tags: c#, header, user-defined-types

I have a C library that I included in a C# project by using a C++ wrapper. The library uses a header which contains some defined types, and I want to use those types in my C# project. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no possibility to "include" a C header into C#. You have to define a `struct` in C# to use the same data structure See [C# calling C function that returns struct with fixed size char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320502/c-sharp-calling-c-function-that-returns-struct-with-fixed-size-char-array) for an example.